# Turn on DEP mode with white list

Tags: nsis

How can i activate Dep mode with white list in NSIS?

"Windows Option: Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select"

My code:

```
!define DEP_SYSTEM_POLICY_TYPE_OPTOUT 3 ; on, use white list

WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" "$INSTDIR\MY.exe" "DisableNXShowUI"
```

Comment: Do you want to change the system DEP policy or just exclude you own application? You code seems to be a mix of the two...

Comment: I want to change DEP policy and add a new line in white list

Comment: Where is your code that changes the DEP policy?